# hibernate Query By Example disapperar in v 6.0.0

Tags: hibernate, query-by-example

I used in the past hibernate QBE as :

```
Session session = (Session) em.unwrap(Session.class);
Example example = Example.create(entityFrom)
```

This code is compiled normaly until Hibernate core version 5.6

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But if I use version 6.0.0  , code doesn't compile , it seams Example, Criterion classes are removed !

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0.Beta1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Some idea ? I need to use QBE facility !

thanks